# align every object in the middle

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

so, i have this page https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHa7w.jpg
and i would like to align all the divs into it, how do i do that?

i think i have to change something in the middlepane class but i don't know what, i tried changing the float from left to middle but it just messes up the page so idk.

btw I'm new to css/html so sry if it's bad

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>idk</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-principale.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-principale-altro.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="leftpane">
            <div>
                <p>idk</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middlepane">
            <div class="container-immagini">
                <img src="immagini/immagini-poesie/1.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightpane">
            <div>
                <p>idk</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the css:

```
    body,
    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .leftpane {
        /*setting di pagina*/
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        /*altro*/
        background-color: #EFEDE1;
    }
    
    .middlepane {
        /*setting di pagina*/
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        /*altro*/
        background-color: #EFEDE1;
    }
    
    .rightpane {
        /*setting di pagina*/
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        /*altro*/
        background-color: #EFEDE1;
    }

    .leftpane div {
        /*settings iniziali per centrarlo*/
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        /*impostazioni del colore del quadrato*/
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #E7B2B2;
    }
    
    .leftpane div p {
        /*base
            questo e' il colore della scritta*/
        color: #EFEDE1;
        font-size: 70px;
        /*per spostarlo al centro*/
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    /*
        Playfair Display - 900
        colore = EFEDE1
        sfondo = E7B2B2
    */
    /*****************centro****************/
    
    .container-immagini {
        /*settings iniziali per centrarlo*/
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: black;
        /*dimensioni immagini*/
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
    }
    
    .container-immagini img {
        /*gli do la dimensione in base alla classe prima*/
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    /*****************destra****************/
    
    .rightpane div {
        /*settings iniziali per centrarlo*/
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        /*impostazioni del colore del quadrato*/
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #E7B2B2;
    }
    
    .rightpane div p {
        /*base
            questo e' il colore della scritta*/
        color: #EFEDE1;
        font-size: 70px;
        /*per spostarlo al centro*/
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "align all the divs into it" ?

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you want to align them vertically all you need to do is to change:

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

to:

```
margin: 50% 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
```

inside your
*.rightpane div* and *.leftpane div* selectors

so it would look something like this:

```
.leftpane div {
    /*settings iniziali per centrarlo*/
    margin: 50% 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    /*impostazioni del colore del quadrato*/
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #E7B2B2;
}

...

.rightpane div {
    /*settings iniziali per centrarlo*/
    margin: 50% 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    /*impostazioni del colore del quadrato*/
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #E7B2B2;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

To align items both vertically and horizontally, you can set the parent element's `display` to `flex`. Then set the `align-items` and `justify-content` property to `center`.

```css
#parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.align {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="align"></div>
  <div class="align"></div>
  <div class="align"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, I don't recommend relying heavily on floats. You can try to use flexbox or css grid instead, it'll save you a lot of headaches.

Here's some resource that will help you.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/